# Problem with np.vectorize function in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I have created this code as below:

```
def scalar_function(x, y):
    if x <= y:
        z = x*y
    else:
        z = x/y
    return z
```

And

```
def vector_function(x, y):
    vfunc = np.vectorize(scalar_function)
    return vfunc
```

But when I try to put: `vector_function([1, 2, 3, 4], 2)`, the output is `<numpy.vectorize at 0x226a1d9aeb8>` instead of resulting array of numbers.

Can anyone point out my mistake? Thanks.

Comment: You aren't doing anything with `x` and `y`  Some place you need `vfunc(x,y)`

Comment: Don't put too much effort into learning `np.vectorize`.  There are more important things in numpy.

Comment: I see! Thanks for your help and advice!! :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have return `return vfunc` which return Vectorized function That you got. you may want `return vfunc(x,y)`

```py
>>> def vector_function(x, y):
        vfunc = np.vectorize(scalar_function)
        return vfunc(x, y)

>>> vector_function([1, 2, 3, 4], 2)
array([2, 4, 1, 2])
```

Comment: I don't think this answer is very useful. In the end, all of it could be replaced by `vector_function = np.vectorize(scalar_function)`, so why make it so complicated?

Comment: @NilsWerner I was just solving issue from existing code. where OP code broken or faced issue. Obviously it could replace by `vector_function = np.vectorize(scalar_function)`

Comment: Then why don't you suggest the *proper solution*?

Comment: I guess this is also proper solution of given question. By the way OP wanted to know where is issue in that code and i pointed out that. I did not consider any readability or optimized solution as it not asked.

Answer (score -1):

There is no need for `np.vectorize`:

```
x = np.asarray(x)
y = np.asarray(y)
np.where(x <= y, x*y, x/y)
```

does the same and is *actually vectorized*.